# Magento: Redirecting to a phtml page from a controller?

Tags: magento, redirect

I have a controller and from there I want to redirect to a certain phtml page. The page is stored in *app\design\frontend\default\mystuff\template\catalog\product\view\myphtml.phtml*.

How can I redirect to this page from my controller?

Thanks!

Comment: You actually want to *render* that template with your controller, not redirect to it.

The template *likely* needs a block class in order to render properly. Also, given the location, you will need to load a product object instance for this to work

Perhaps you want to use your template to render the product view block? If that's the case, just use layout XML to update the product view block.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me some details how to do that, please?

Answer (score 3):

*Latest: OP indicated the need to show this template on its own*

If you want to display *just* your template, you can do this in your controller action:

```
public yourAction()
{
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
                                   ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/myphtml.phtml');

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $block->toHtml()
    );
}
```

You could also use layout XML, kicking off in your controller:

```
public yourAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout(false)->renderLayout(); //false keeps default handle from loading
}
```

And in (ideally) your module's layout XML, do:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
        <block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/myphtml.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
</layout>
```

If you need to know your full action name (the `yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction`), you can get that info in the controller action by `echo $this->getFullActionName();`.

Finally, if you are trying to load a product view page that looks like the standard one, but on your own action, you can do this:

```
public yourAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

And then in your layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/myphtml.phtml" name="your.block" />
        </reference>
    </yourmodule_yourcontroller_youraction>
</layout>
```

---

*Previous: OP has indicated that he/she wants to change the template which is used for the product view block, answering accordingly.*

Magento's layout XML system handles this task quite well. As you are the end implementer, you have access to use a special layout file named *local.xml*, which should go in your custom theme folder (likely `app/design/frontend/default/mystuff/layout/`).

The file should appear as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <tpl>catalog/product/view/myphtml.phtml</tpl>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Your layout instructions are merged and processed along with all of the others. For reference, the `product.info` block is established in the *catalog.xml* layout file. The above instructions could be stated in plain English as the following:

> For the rendering scope identified by the full action name `catalog_product_view` and for the block instance identified in layout by the name `product.info`, call its `setTemplate()` method with the argument `catalog/product/view/myphtml.phtml`.

Comment: Thanks, I dont want the product view, I want to display the phtml on a completely new page, not the product view. How would I do that?

Comment: Updated my answer. Keep in mind that the OOB product view relies on controller-level work to instantiate product and prepare the view, which is a bit atypical and breaks the portability of the view model.